# is it dangerous for the processor core to be *always* loaded at 100%?

Tags: performance, xeon, central-processing-unit

In my HFT software I plan to use one core for stock index calculation. That would be simply `while(true)` loop without any delays which will calculate (sum and multiply) components as often as possible (so millions times per second) and I plan to do that 8 hours per day every day.

I was never before loading my computer to 100% full time every day regullary. May it be dangerous? Do processor has kind of "resource" (very big of course) after which it can stopped working?

Comment: Easy bit of information. What type of hardware (make+model) do you plan to run your trading strategy on?

Comment: @ewwhite hp dl360p gen8

Comment: Yep, a great server.

Comment: Although, personally, I'd recommend architecting it in such a way as to allow clean shutdown.  So, `while(active)`, not `while(true)` (with   a 'shutdown' public method).

Comment: I've been doing this with even consumer-grade equipment for many years and never had a problem (distributed computing programs keeping my CPU at 100% non-stop).  It sucks down more juice, and generates more heat, but as long as you've accounted for that, there's no danger.  No moving parts in a CPU, so no risk or it wearing out or whatever.

Comment: @HopelessN00b IIRC, I remember reading an article that CPUs that run hot are more likely to have an eventual short form by the micro-wires migrating. I can't find a solid reference to this now though.. something to consider still

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's no danger (when using server-class hardware).

I've run hundreds of HFT systems where we'd designate a CPU core to run a spinlock thread (to reduce interrupts) or have strategies pegged to specific CPU cores for the duration of the trading day. This is what the CPUs were designed for. I can say that I've never had a processor fail in this context.

In your situation, are you using a proper server? Other factors to consider are cooling, redundant fans, power supplies, etc. But those are standard items for any production system.

Comment: Italso works with non server hardware when properly put together. P24/7 is quite irrelevant here - anything that does not heat up long term will work. If you have a heat problem, it shows a LOT sooner than after one day ;) But you are right on server hardware, especially for example most have passive CPU coolers (air pressed through by fans in the CASE, but that is redundant and not a single fan on the CPU).

Comment: Just thinking about the practical aspects of a financial trading system. I'd hate to see this running on a desktop for reasons outside of the CPU health. E.g. a power supply failing and taking you out of the market is a much bigger concern than the system overheating or the CPU failing.

Comment: Can be handled with redundant systems. The main reason some people go non-server CPU is that normally you can have a higher frequency there ;) Heck, there was once a company selling overclocked rack servers - with compressor cooling ;) Guess for whom ;) When you fight to be faster than the next one in the same rack, that may be what it takes. Not that I would ever do that - I am happy not going time critical.

Answer (score 5):

Thousands of scientific clusters worldwide consider it a suboptimal (or bad) situation when there are cores that are not at 100% CPU load. Real servers with proper server grade hardware are designed for this.

Answer (score 5):

In general, no, though what you should be looking at is load, but temperatures. You might want to simulate the load (perhaps with [superpi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_PI) on windows, [prime95](http://www.mersenne.org/) on linux and windows or some other stress test application, or your actual application) and run the process until the temperature stabilises -similar to what an overclocker would do.

You want this temperature to be under the maximum rated temperature for that processor -look up the datasheet for that. Then see if your cooling solution is adequate and presumably adjust it as needed. I can't suggest monitoring software, unfortunately without knowing an OS - the usual suspects such as nagios may work, but for a initial 'burn in', something like [lmsensors](http://lm-sensors.org/) or [pcwizard](http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/pc-wizard.html) may do for a single system.

Most modern processors will simply throttle down if they overheat - [intel has a page on this](http://www.intel.com/support/processors/sb/CS-029426.htm). It would be horrible for your application if performance is critical, but its more likely the system will shut down or act strange rather than burn itself out. Thats a sign the processor is overtaxed, and bad things are happening - review your cooling choices in that case.